# How to fix dataexporter ClassDefFoundError in PrimeFaces dataexporter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, itext

I am trying to practice the export functionality in Primefaces and I was trying to check the `<p:dataexporter>` element. I  have added the itextpdf-5.3.0.jar in the Libraries and classpath in the project in the Jdeveloper. However when I tried to use it in the click on the commandbutton for exporting the DataTable to PDF, I got the below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
    at org.primefaces.component.export.PDFExporter.export(PDFExporter.java:53)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:97)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:778)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:173)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    ... 39 more
```

There is only one jar file and I tried to download other jar files and to try the export, however it is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All iText versions older than December 2009 are obsolete and should no longer be used. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially for more info. (There are also a number of unofficial iText versions with a version number 4.)

How do you recognize these obsolete versions? The easiest way is to look at the package names. When the package refers to my name (`lowagie`), then you are using an obsolete, unsupported version of iText.

You have downloaded iText 5.3.0 dating from June 20, 2012. (Which is also pretty old; why not use a more recent version?) Since December 2009, all the package names were changed from `com.lowagie` into `com.itextpdf`. See the [changelog](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/50) for more detail.

Your error message says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
```

That is correct. The package `com.lowagie.text` refers to a version of iText that is older than December 2009 (and all of these versions have been removed from the official download sites). You are using a version that has a class named `com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException`. That version doesn't contain any class named `com.lowagie.text.DocumentException`.

Comment: Thanks so which one I should download and use?

Comment: I hope that you understand that I can not help you with this question, given the fact that I am the CEO of the iText Group.

Comment: I have downloaded now the version itext-5.4.0 and it is still the same? I am wondering that the error is produced from another files?

Comment: @Learner30: read the response by @ BrunoLowagie carefully. You can only use itext versions up to 2.1.7 with PrimeFaces DataExporter. If you want to use newer versions, you have to download the PrimeFaces source and fully refactor the DataExporter

Comment: Thanks for your explanation .. I just have understood the issue. So you mean even if I download earlier versions for example version 2.1.7  that it will not work?

Comment: No, then you did *not* understand. It works *just/only* with 2.1.7